# Locking strategy with PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, propertychanged

I've defined a class with a number of "observable" properties.  Internally the class contains a single thread that performs I/O; e.g.

```
public class Foo {
  private final PropertyChangeSupport support;
  private State state;

  public Foo() { this.support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this); }

  public synchronized State getState() { return state; }

  public synchronized void setState(State state) {
    if (this.state != state) {
      State oldState = this.state;
      this.state = state;

      // Fire property change *whilst still holding the lock*.
      support.firePropertyChange("state", oldState, state);
    }
  }

  public synchronized void start() {
    // Start I/O Thread, which will call setState(State) in some circumstances.
    new Thread(new Runnable() ...
  }
}
```

My question is: Should I avoid firing property change events whilst holding onto the class's lock?  ... *or* perhaps I should be firing property change events from a single dedicated thread (e.g. "event-multicaster" thread)?

The current design is resulting in a deadlock whereby thread A takes out a lock on an external class: `Bar`, and then tries to call a method on `Foo` and take out a second lock.  However, at the same time the I/O thread calls `setState(State)` obtaining the lock on `Foo`, which propagates a property changed event out to the containing class `Bar` and attempts to get the lock on this class ... resulting in deadlock.  In other words, the property change callback design means I cannot effectively control the order in which my locks are being obtained.

My current workaround is to make state `volatile` and remove the `synchronized` keywords but this seems like a kludge; for one thing it means the order in which the property change events are fired is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to have other threads call back into your class from the notification loop, then you need to reduce the scope of synchronization, using a synchronized block rather than synchronizing the entire message (this is copied from your post, no idea if it compiles):

```
public void setState(State state) {
    State oldState = null;
    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.state != state) {
        oldState = this.state;
        this.state = state;
      }
    }

    if (oldState != null)
      support.firePropertyChange("state", oldState, state);
  }
```

Hold locks for the shortest amount of time possible. And think about replacing these callbacks with a synchronized message queue (look in java.util.concurrent).

---

Edit, to generalize on the answer and add some philosophy.

Rant first: multi-threaded programming is hard. Anyone who tells you differently is trying to sell you something. Creating a lot of interdependent connections in a multi-threaded program leads to subtle bugs, if not outright insanity.

The best way that I know of to simplify multi-threaded programming is to write independent modules with well-defined start and stop points -- in other words, the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). An individual actor is single-threaded; you can easily comprehend and test it in isolation.

The pure actor model fits well with event notifications: the actor is invoked in response to an event, and performs some action. It doesn't care whether another event has fired since it started. Sometimes, that's not enough: you need to make a decision based on state managed by another thread. That's OK: the actor can look at that state (in a synchronized manner) and make decisions.

The key thing to remember (as Tom Hawtin notes in his comment) is that the state you read now may be different a millisecond from now. You can't *ever* write code that assumes that you know the exact state of an object. If you feel that you need to do this, you need to rethink your design.

And a final comment: Doug Lea is smarter than you or I. Don't try to reinvent the classes in [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: That's definitely an improvement but won't guarantee that property change events are fired in the correct order.

Comment: Welcome to multi-threaded programming. That's why I said that a better approach is to use a message queue as mediator.

Comment: Thanks - I see your point.  I guess this ties in with me mentioning having a dedicated thread for firing PropertyChangeEvents.  A dedicated thread could read and propagate from the queue so the API would not change.  It would also be better in that my I/O thread never ventured outside my class ... but no so nice in that when an event was received there'd be no guarantee that the variable still had that value :-(

Comment: If the current state of the variable is important, then you need to use a polling mechanism. If the fact that it changed is important, then you can use notification mechanism.

Comment: Of course with polling the value could change immediately after the get.